# Escrever na tela Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, html5-canvas

Preciso fazer uma área no form que o usuário assine digitalmente com uma caneta para tela de touch para armazenar a assinatura do mesmo.

Como se o mesmo estivesse escrevendo em um papel mas na tela.

Li sobre o Canvas mas so aprendi a fazer linhas, retângulos ou formas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue código

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">  
 <title>PresTO - Assinatura Digital</title>
 <!-- Jquery -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <style type="text/css">
 #canvas{
  background-color: #EFC;
 }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var canvasWidth = 300;
 var canvasHeight = 150;
 var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvasDiv');
  canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.setAttribute('width', canvasWidth);
  canvas.setAttribute('height', canvasHeight);
  canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
  canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas);
  if(typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
  canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
  }
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");


  $('#canvas').mousedown(function(e){
  var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

   paint = true;
   addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
   redraw();
  });

  $('#canvas').mousemove(function(e){
   if(paint){
  addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
  redraw();
  }
  });

  $('#canvas').mouseup(function(e){
   paint = false;
  });

  $('#canvas').mouseleave(function(e){
   paint = false;
  });

  var clickX = new Array();
  var clickY = new Array();
  var clickDrag = new Array();
  var paint;

  function addClick(x, y, dragging)
 {
   clickX.push(x);
   clickY.push(y);
   clickDrag.push(dragging);
 }

  function redraw(){
 context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);  

 context.strokeStyle = "#df4b26";
 context.lineJoin = "round";
 context.lineWidth = 5;

 for(var i=0; i < clickX.length; i++) {        
   context.beginPath();
   if(clickDrag[i] && i){
    context.moveTo(clickX[i-1], clickY[i-1]);
  }else{
   context.moveTo(clickX[i]-1, clickY[i]);
  }
   context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
   context.closePath();
   context.stroke();
  }
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="canvasDiv"></div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Da uma olhadinha [aqui](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/#demo-simple). Vê se te ajuda...

Comment: @JuniorNunes fiz exatamente como o exemplo porem nao funciona. vou dar mais uma olhada. obrigado

Comment: @EzequielTavares podes mostrar o q vc tentou de código?

Comment: @I'mBlueDaBaDee editei a pergunta com o codigo que useii abraço

Comment: Repare Ezequiel que no seu console, está acusando erro

Answer (score 10):

Seguindo o exemplo do link postado pelo @JuniorNunes.

O Autor deixou esqueceu algumas partes como declarar as variaveis `canvasWidth` e `canvasHeight` referentes ao tamanho da area que voce pode desenhar (canvas)

Testado com mouse no: IE11, Chrome, Firefox e Edge
Testado touch: tela do note touchscreen

**EDIT**
Adicionados equivalentes para suporte a touch. dado que o evento disparado por um dispositivo touch é não é o `mousedown` `mouseup` e `mousemove` e sim `touchstart` `touchend` e `touchmove`, respectivamente.

```js
var canvasWidth = 300;
var canvasHeight = 150;
var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvasDiv');
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.setAttribute('width', canvasWidth);
canvas.setAttribute('height', canvasHeight);
canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas);
if(typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
 canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
}
context = canvas.getContext("2d");


$('#canvas').mousedown(function(e){
  var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
  
  paint = true;
  addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
  redraw();
});

$('#canvas').mousemove(function(e){
  if(paint){
    addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
    redraw();
  }
});

$('#canvas').mouseup(function(e){
  paint = false;
});

$('#canvas').mouseleave(function(e){
  paint = false;
});

var clickX = new Array();
var clickY = new Array();
var clickDrag = new Array();
var paint;

function addClick(x, y, dragging)
{
  clickX.push(x);
  clickY.push(y);
  clickDrag.push(dragging);
}

// Set up touch events for mobile, etc
canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
        mousePos = getTouchPos(canvas, e);
  var touch = e.touches[0];
  var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousedown", {
    clientX: touch.clientX,
    clientY: touch.clientY
  });
  canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function (e) {
  var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mouseup", {});
  canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function (e) {
  var touch = e.touches[0];
  var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousemove", {
    clientX: touch.clientX,
    clientY: touch.clientY
  });
  canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
}, false);

// Get the position of a touch relative to the canvas
function getTouchPos(canvasDom, touchEvent) {
  var rect = canvasDom.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: touchEvent.touches[0].clientX - rect.left,
    y: touchEvent.touches[0].clientY - rect.top
  };
}

// Prevent scrolling when touching the canvas
document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
  if (e.target == canvas) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);
document.body.addEventListener("touchend", function (e) {
  if (e.target == canvas) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);
document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", function (e) {
  if (e.target == canvas) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);

function redraw(){
  context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // Clears the canvas
  
  context.strokeStyle = "#df4b26";
  context.lineJoin = "round";
  context.lineWidth = 5;
   
  for(var i=0; i < clickX.length; i++) {  
    context.beginPath();
    if(clickDrag[i] && i){
      context.moveTo(clickX[i-1], clickY[i-1]);
     }else{
       context.moveTo(clickX[i]-1, clickY[i]);
     }
     context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
     context.closePath();
     context.stroke();
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background:#eee;
}
#canvas {
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvasDiv"></div>
```

Comment: andrepaulo, de uma olhada como eu usei o codigo e nao funcionou. abraço

Comment: Acredito que não funciona no IE.. o autor disse que tem um Js a mais pra inserir pra que funcione no IE.. qual browser vc esta testando?

Comment: uso firefox e chrome

Comment: testei no Firefox, Chrome, IE e Edge, está funcionando... nem pelo snippet da minha resposta voce consegue ver?

Comment: nao sei porque mas adicionei o $(document ready ... e deu certo. obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: testei no tablet e nao funciona. tens alguma ideia? pois ate entao tinha testado no PC

Comment: vi esse artigo aqui, acredito que possa ajudar. https://bencentra.com/code/2014/12/05/html5-canvas-touch-events.html

Comment: de qualquer forma, atualizei a resposta de forma a suportar dispositivos touch, testando na tela do meu note. nao testei no tablet

Comment: andrepaulo, funcionou perfeitamente ... apenas observei que quando muda a orientação ele se desconfigura (isso posso resolver travando a orientação do app para modo paisagem) o que , (se nao for abusar da sua paciencia), seria aperfeiçoar a resolução do traçado na tela, conhece alguma solução?

Comment: nao faco ideia de como melhorar resolucao, mas acho que isso daria uma bela, proxima pergunta pro stack, não acha?

Comment: bem lembrado andre paulo